# isolate scope not working within ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

http://plnkr.co/edit/03O57QBeMLzFiwdvaWOj?p=preview

I'm trying to create an interface that allows users to add blocks to a page and edit them.  The user clicks the "add block" button and then selects the type of block she would like to add.

My problem is that none of the buttons work after the user clicks "add block".  If I comment out the scope in the selectBlock directive, the buttons will work but then I won't be able to pass block ids around.

```
// comment this out and the buttons will work
scope: {
      lrBlockId: '@'
    },
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can give your directive access to the functions using the `'&'` symbol in the scope property definition:

```
app.directive('selectBlock', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      lrBlockId: '@',
      addHeaderBlock: '&',
      addGalleryBlock: '&',
      addSignupBlock: '&'
    },
    templateUrl: 'select-block-type.html'
  };
});
```

Then, you need to map the correct functions into these properties using element attributes:

```
<div ng-if='block.type === "select"' >
    <div select-block lr-block-id="block.block_id"
      add-header-block="addHeaderBlock(block.block_id)" 
      add-gallery-block="addGalleryBlock()" 
      add-signup-block="addSignupBlock()"></div>
</div>
```

Here is a working demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/mPjNDOw3El5isHQGwSYk?p=preview